# Node.js: how to send events across modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, module

I created two modules, "person" and "group", with "group" depending on "person":

person.js:

```
var events = require('events');

exports.Person = function() {
    var personEvents = new events.EventEmitter();

    function generateEvent(args) {
        console.log("Emitting event with args "+JSON.stringify(args));
        personEvents.emit("myEvent", args);
    }

    return {
        personEvents: personEvents,
        generateEvent: generateEvent
    };
}
```

group.js:

```
var PERSON = require("person.js").Person();
var events = require('events');

exports.Group = function() {
    function handleEvent(args) {
        console.log("Caught event with args "+JSON.stringify(args));
    }

    PERSON.personEvents.on("myEvent", function(args) {
        handleEvent(args);
    });
}
```

Now I have the main program main.js as a separate module:

```
var PERSON = require("person.js").Person();
var GROUP = require("group.js").Group();

PERSON.generateEvent({ type: "bla" });
```

When I execute "node ./main.js", I will see the message that the event was generated, but the event is not caught.  It seems that the listener in the group module is not bound to the same "personEvents" variable created in the person module in the main namespace.

I am rather new at javascript and its implications for programming.  I used examples I found on the internet to get the code I have so far, but I feel that this may not be the correct way to setup the modules and the cross-module events.

Can someone explain to me how I should setup the modules so I can generate events in one module and catch them in another?
Thanks!

Comment: usually modules don't talk to one another...

Comment: I want to be able to generate events in one module that other modules can listen to and take action if needed, creating loosely coupled components.  However, if this is not what the node module infrastructure is intended for, then I guess I must rethink the whole design of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `var PERSON = require("person.js").Person();`, that creates a new instance. So, when you call it in `group.js`, that creates a separate object/instance than the one you create when you call it in `main.js`.  You could get around this by passing the `Person` object to `Group` when you create it in `main.js` like:

group.js

```
var events = require('events');

exports.Group = function(PERSON) {
    function handleEvent(args) {
        console.log("Caught event with args "+JSON.stringify(args));
    }

    PERSON.personEvents.on("myEvent", function(args) {
        handleEvent(args);
    });
}
```

main.js

```
var PERSON = require("person.js").Person();
var GROUP = require("group.js").Group(PERSON);

PERSON.generateEvent({ type: "bla" });
```

**That being said, that's not a very loosely coupled system.**  If you want something more loosely coupled, then `Group` and `Person` should not reference each other at all and the communication between the two should happen in `main.js`.

You can accomplish that by changing `group.js` and `main.js` to something like this:

group.js

```
var events = require('events');

exports.Group = function() {
    function handleEvent(args) {
        console.log("Caught event with args "+JSON.stringify(args));
    }
}
```

main.js

```
var PERSON = require("person.js").Person();
var GROUP = require("group.js").Group();

PERSON.on('myEvent', function(args) {
    GROUP.handleEvent(args);
});

PERSON.generateEvent({ type: "bla" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  This led me to follow an alternative approach: I now created "var messageBus = new events.EventEmitter()" in main.js for the events and pass this messageBus variable to both PERSON and GROUP objects for listening/emitting.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I could help! Using an `EventEmitter` like that is a good way to do it too.